# SXA Search Boosting rule not having affect on Azure site

Tags: sxa

I created a search scope for boosting based on a rule.

[image]

I set the search box and search result scope to use this boosted search.

Works completely as expected locally - but when I deploy to azure the boosting seems to have no affect at all.

I have rebuilt the index, and have checked that the navigation title field is in the index by setting a nice random value in that field for a page, and after publishing confirms that it is picked up in the search results.

There are no errors in the log on executing the search (querying the logs in application insights).

I read in another post that potentially azure search does not handle contains properly - but even changing to "is case-insensitively equal to" does not work on a single word.

Here's an example - where the pages with the word Sample should appear at the top of the list. 
[image]

The search query according to logs is:

> [sitecore_sxa_web_index]: &search=(sxacontent:(/.*holiday.*/) AND
>   (template_1:(53d07dd880b148cf8e2cbc36cff7dc5b) OR
>   template_1:(dc876a19c0de42788ef491ecb3c82b79) OR
>   template_1:(71f7269a47484737aec3924ddf328142) OR
>   template_1:(3e4af7d2a9e14357bca75108dc7a5416) OR
>   template_1:(ac2a523742c84f5490c6dbe51f9d6a0c)))&$filter=((search.ismatchscoring('navigationtitle_s:(/.*holiday.*/)^49',
>   null, 'full', null) or not (compat_prefix__name_s eq '')) and
>   latestversion_1 and (path_1/any(t:t eq
>   'c57e57c57b1d47afaeac3b9532763b10')) and searchable and
>   (path_1/any(t:t eq
>   'c57e57c57b1d47afaeac3b9532763b10')))&queryType=full&$skip=0&$top=20&$count=true

Changing boost score from 50 to 49 made no difference.

Comment: Can you show me your search queries?

Comment: And if you try to use 49 instead of 50? as Matthew Dresser mentioned here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/azure-search-boosting-not-working/19472#19472 boost values which were powers of two helped him. 49 is 7 powered 2 so it could help...

Comment: I assume that locally you are using Solr, right?

Comment: @PeterProcházka that is correct - I am locally using Solr.  Changing to 49 makes no difference.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski have added to the item - thanks!

Comment: Strange issue, the query is almost fine. I just don't know what are those null's here: `(search.ismatchscoring('navigationtitle_s:(/.holiday./)^49', null, 'full', null)`.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski it seems that contains only works in azure search if you type in a partial word match.  so if I was to put in "holida" instead of "holiday" then the boost would work. The other alternative is exact matching but its more likely a user would put in say 1 word of the two that make up the page navigation title.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski turns out I needed to use equals to - but the comparison option I first tried for that wasn't supported.  Have added the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Azure search - if you use `contains` then it does a partial word match as in "Samp" will boost "Sample Page 1".  If you use "Sample" it is not a partial word so does not get boosted.

To use the word matching in a phrase you need to use `is equals to` rule.

I also discovered that the `"is case-insensitively equal to"`, `"is not case-insensitively equal to"`, and `"matches the regular expression"` comparison types are not supported for this type of rule. A request to hide them has been submitted as I initially thought the case-insensitively equals sounded fit for purpose.

[image]